# Extending wordpress search to include excerpts and taxonomies?

Tags: custom-taxonomy, search, excerpt, customization

Apologies for the lack of code, but I have no idea where to start with this - is it possible to extend Wordpress's search function to include excerpts and (custom) taxonomies as well as the standard title and post content in search results? i.e. search results don't include posts that contain keywords found in excerpts or taxonomies, is it possible to include them?

Ideally, I'd like to do this without a plugin if possible, is there a way to extend it via functions.php?

Thanks for any pointers.

Osu

Comment: There is no really easy way to do this, you will have to use a plugin or create your own search code.

Comment: @Wick - thanks for getting back to me, I assume the 'Search Everything' plugin is going to be the easiest solution then?

Answer (score 1):

With Wordpress 4.2.2 I'm using the following (admittedly fragile) method to search excerpts as well as the content and title without a plugin.

This is the relevant snippet from functions.php.

```
add_filter('posts_where', 'custom_posts_where');

function custom_posts_where($where) {
    if (is_search()) {
        $where = preg_replace(
            "/(\w+).post_title LIKE ('%.*?%')/",
            "$1.post_title LIKE $2) OR ($1.post_excerpt LIKE $2",
            $where);
    }

return $where;
}
```

Comment: This is a good start but seems fragile like you said. It would be great if wordpress would provide some core hooks to add and prioritize different search fields and logic in general.